# Selenium webdriver Xpath with dot (.) in attribute name

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html:

```
<table id="oTable">
<tbody>
    <tr mote.id="12345">
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr mote.id="54321">
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to locate the row with `mote.id` and click the first `td`-tag

```
WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@mote.id='12345']/td[1]"));
```

But I get the following Error:

```
Bad token, expected: ] got: .
```

Comment: Try to escape out your dot with \.

Comment: have you tried to use `xpath` without `mote.`, just like `//tr[@id='12345']/td[1]` ?

Comment: @Andersson The problem is that i also have a row with parentmote.id="12345"

Comment: @Calle, Jagdeep's suggestion about `//tr[@mote\.id='12345']/td[1]` doesn't work also?

Comment: @Calle could you try getting all the rows and then using selenium's `GetAttribute` method to filter the rows from within your code? So do `Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//table[@id='oTable']/tbody/tr"))` and then use a for loop to go through each one and remove ones that either don't have the attribute "mote.id" or don't have the correct value in the attribute. Perhaps the `GetAttribute` will be more lax about the period in the middle of the attribute than the XPaths.

Comment: @Andersson, No i cant escape with \. i get Illegal excape character

Comment: Can't you directly locate the td element without tr id? `<td>Status</td>`

Comment: @Calle did you fix this issue?

Comment: Use mote\\.id
You need to escape . with \\

Answer (score 1):

To locate the `<td>` element, use :

```
WebElement element = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Status')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"))
```

No need of mote.id.

There are alternative apporaches as well by using

```
findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(0);
```

Comment: I think Calle has probably simplified his example. I doubt he would be asking the question if a simple XPath like that could work.

Comment: Thats correct @BenChand. There are many rows and the only attribute thats is known is mote.id

Answer (score 0):

You need two `\\` before the dot, first `\` so that the second one gets through, and the second to escape the dot so it becomes literal. Try `\\.`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Selenium are you on? I'm on 2.52.0 (latest as of now) and on Python. Your xpath works:

```
>>> print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@mote.id='12345']").get_attribute('innerHTML')

        <td>Status</td>
        <td>1</td>
>>>
>>> print driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@mote.id='12345']/td[1]").get_attribute('innerHTML')
Status
```

Alternatively, you could write a helper function to find all the relevant `tr` elements and then check each one's `mote.id` for the you want.

```
>>> def get_mote_by_id(mote_id):
...     elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='oTable']/tbody/tr")
...     for elem in elems:
...         if elem.get_attribute('mote.id') == mote_id:
...             return elem
...
>>>
>>> print get_mote_by_id('12345').get_attribute('innerHTML')

        <td>Status</td>
        <td>1</td>
```

(This is obviously slower than an xpath which matches directly but if it's version issue, then it's a workaround.) And Yes, it's in Python not Java but should be clear what the Java version should do.

PS: Any way you get your devs or product vendor to use `mote_id` or `moteid` instead of `mote.id`? That would be compliant with attribute names in HTML and XML.